# Hide Block on Particular Page with Bootstrap

Tags: theming, blocks, hooks, bootstrap-theme

I have a block called 'calendar' that I display on all events pages. events* such as events/today/, events/all/ etc.

A constraint that I have is that the block must be displayed on all events pages but on one particular page. The block must be hidden when the user is using a mobile device.

My thought process was to simply apply the bootstrap 'hidden-xs' class to the block. But the constraint is not satisfied as it would trigger on all the events pages.

What would be the easiest way to implement this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've gone with a pure CSS implementation. By simply using a class in the body element and a media query. I'll add a more detailed answer to explain the solution shortly.

Comment: Just a note. You can use [Browser Class](https://www.drupal.org/project/browserclass) module in Drupal which will add classes to < body > tag based on OS and Browser user is viewing your site in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a media query and the node-type-event class generated in the body element to target and hide the views-event-block.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: $screen-md) {
  .node-type--event{
    .views-event-block{
      display: none;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use combination of media query  to achieve this.Using media query hide the block under mobile resolutions . For example

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
.block-class {
    display: none;
  }
}
```